# Automating connnection/deconnection of DNS filter's VPN when a specific fingerprint is recognised

Tags: android, automation, dns, samsung

I installed DNSfilter on the family tablet to prevent my children from accessing YouTube. As it happens, I need YouTube for professional purposes (following tutorials in particular) and so as not to continually activate/deactivate the VPN I thought of Samsung's Modes & Routines which, along with Routines +, allows when a specific fingerprint is detected (mine in this case) to connect/disconnect from a VPN network automatically such as the one DNSfilter uses. That's exactly what I had in mind! Unfortunately, I can't do it with the Dns filter VPN network: Samsung sends an error message specifying that it must not be an application VPN. My idea is simple: when my fingerprint is detected then automatically disconnect from the dns filter VPN network and keep it activated when connecting with code & other fingerprint or facial recognition. Would there be any other solution to achieve this? For example, by making SAMSNG believe that it's a manual VPN and not an application or other service that allows you to do this please without rooting the phone for fear of compromising security (I also have my bank's application which doesn't support root). I sincerely thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.